# Remove time from date

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm having a problem with `NSDate` instance.

For the date I'm receiving `2012-08-16 00:00:00 +0000`.
But I need to remove from the `00:00:00 +0000`.

Is there any way to do that?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *eventDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDate]; // current Tile

NSLog(@"date %@",eventDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
NSLog(@"date %@",[formatter stringFromDate:eventDate]);
```

A `NSDate` is just a single point in time. It does not know how it's value should be formatted, that's what `NSDateFormatter` is for.

`NSLog(@"date %@",eventDate);` prints the default string representation of the date.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. You have `eventDate` which is a `NSDate`. What do you need exactly?

Comment: the date should be in NSDate tyep not NSStirng. [formatter stringFromDate:eventDate] gives a string.

Comment: @user1397784: As @benzado and I pointer out, a `NSDate` is just an absolute point in time. It knows nothing about hours, minutes or time zones. In your `NSLog(@"date %@",eventDate)` statement, you in fact print also a string, because `[eventDate description]` is called internally, and that gives a default string representation. - Perhaps you can state more clearly what you intend to do with the date. As @benzado already said, `NSDateComponents` might be more appropriate for your task.

Comment: @user1397784: And have a look at the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i).

Answer (score 1):

A date formatter converts strings into dates and dates into strings. An NSDate represents an point in time, regardless how you created it. In your code you seem to be thinking that the NSDate will "remember" that the formatter it came from didn't specify a time of day; it won't. When you call `dateFromString:` it will simply pick 00:00:00 (midnight) as the time.

If you need to work with calendar dates regardless of the time, you can either:

1. Use NSDate objects and ignore the time component. You will need to be wary of time zones, since midnight on August 15th in one time zone can be 11pm on August 14th in another.
2. Use a different data structure to store year, month, and day. NSDateComponents is a good candidate, or you could create your own.